# How to count number of rows having id's starting with A or B?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to display entries in a table. The idea is to strip down the numerical and count `ColumnA` then sort by `ColumnB`:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| A | Main |
| B | Main |
| A1 | External |
| B1 | External |
| A2 | Internal |
| B2 | Internal |
| A3 | Internal |
| A4 | Internal |

I am trying to display the output like this:

| Main | Internal count | External count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Join your data with defined patterns and make conditional count:

```
select pattern, 
       count(case columnB when 'Internal' then 1 end) as internal_cnt,
       count(case columnB when 'External' then 1 end) as external_cnt
from mytable
join (select 'A' pattern union all select 'B') p on columnA like pattern||'%'
group by pattern
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1J6qTOag)

Comment: Thankyou @Ponder. I was looking for such a solution.
Is there any way we can use the join to check for all the available values, that is not just for A or B, can we make this dynamic, in other words, it searches for the available alpha characters and counts each one accordingly. 
Looking for a dynamic way to make this work for any kind of alpha characters - `code` join (select 'A' pattern union all select 'B') p on columnA like pattern||'%' 

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can find all distinct characters and use them as patterns: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PjsOntwl).